# navbar sobrepõe os outros elementos quando o tamanho da página é alterado

Tags: css

Eu tenho esta [aplicação fictícia em R](https://giovani.shinyapps.io/0_example/).

Eu tentei ajustar o `.navbar`, `.sidebar` e o `.value-box` com a propriedade `position: relative;` para evitar a sobreposição de elementos:

```
.navbar {
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
  position: relative; 
}

.value-box {
  position: relative;
}
```

Mas, sempre o `.navbar` atropela os outros elementos, no caso `.sidebar` e o `.value-box` quando modifico o tamanho da tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu objetivo é fazer com que o `.navbar` desça igual ocorre agora, *mas os outros elementos precisam descer/ se ajustar para não serem engolidos pelo `.navbar`*. Algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remova do `body` qualquer `padding-top` e insira o código abaixo na página (no final do `body`):

```
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
   let navHeader = 0;
   if($("#dashboard-container").offset().top < $(".navbar-header").outerHeight()) navHeader = $(".navbar-header").outerHeight();
   $("#dashboard-container").css({"top": ($(".navbar-fixed-top").outerHeight()+10+navHeader) +"px", "position" : "relative"});
   $("#section-sidebar").css("top", ($(".navbar-fixed-top").outerHeight()+10) +"px");
});
```

Por CSS você não consegue saber a altura do navbar, por isso ele fica por cima dos elementos abaixo quando fica maior, só colocando `padding-top` no body não é suficiente, já que a altura do navbar pode variar.

O código acima detecta quando a página é carregada ou quando a janela é redimensionada e reposiciona a lateral (que é fixa) e a div do dahsboard de acordo com a altura do navbar.

Se você não conseguir encontrar onde o `padding-top` no body é inserido, basta definir no seu CSS personalizado (o que você criou. Se não criou um, crie um) e coloque:

```
body{
   padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Isso irá sobrescrever qualquer outro CSS que possa estar adicionando o `padding-top` ao body.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, @Sam. Só um detalhe: quando renderizo a página, ela fica com um grande espaço entre os elementos e o `.navbar`. Após mudar o tamanho da tela e voltar ao tamanho normal, tudo fica bem. Gostaria que quando processasse a página, já ficasse do jeito correto. Sabe o que pode ser isso? Além, como retirar o scroll da página do carousel?

Comment: Quando vc estiver online me avisa.

Comment: Estou online @Sam, obrigado.